# Shortcut to surround an html tag by table/row/cell with their closing tags?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, coderush

Looking for a shortcut in Visual Studio to surround a selected tag by

```
<table><tr><td>my selected element</td></tr></table>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Anything in plain vanilla VS? Web Essentials? Resharper? CodeRush?

Comment: In CR, you can select and hit refactor to surround with "td", then enter, refactor, "td", enter, refactor, "table". You can also use embeddings to define a template. Then you do "refactor button", select embed, <select template> or add a shortcut key to do it in one keystroke. In practice the former is probably most useful unless you really do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush can certainly solve this issue for you.

- Ruben is quite correct. We have a "Surround with Tag" refactoring which can be applied successively with 'td', 'tr' and then 'table' (working from inside out.
- Alternatively you could [create a template](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/11/04/coderush-templates-the-templates-options-page.aspx):

**Structure only**

`<table><tr><td>«Caret»</td></tr></table>`

This would create the table structure you are after and place your caret ready to enter the data of your choice.

**Structure with Paste**

`<table><tr><td>«Paste»</td></tr></table>`

This would create the structure you are after and paste the content of your clipboard inside it.

**Existing Template**

The built-in **.t** template will create a much more complex table structure under your guidance, and plugins can be written to address a specific need.

**NOTE:** These techniques make use of cutting the target element to the clipboard. If your target element is sufficiently complex, this would make selecting and cutting seem like too much work.

**However...** another CodeRush feature (**Smart Cut\Copy**) will make this much easier. Simply position the caret immediately to the left of your target and cut. CodeRush will detect that nothing is selected and will dynamically select the logical element to it's right before continuing with the cut operation.

At this point your task becomes

- Cut
- Invoke template
- (Optionally) paste.

All of these steps are invokable using just the keyboard.

**If all else fails... :)**

If this does not meet your need, please feel free to comment below, or contact me directly (roryb@devexpress.com) and we can discuss your needs in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Surround template in Resharper.

```
<table><tr><td>$SELECTION$$END$</td></tr></table>
```